# Message Receive From Active MQ queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, mq

I had Active MQ Connection Factory get the Connection, get the Session and create receiver from the Queue. I did the Client_Acknowledge here while creating Session. When I got the message in the Queue I receive the message but I did not ack. Noted here and also did not close the connection.

Again in the same connection I tried to receive the same Message. But this time I did not receive message and get null value.

My question is, can I receive the same message twice in the same connection from Active Mq when it's a synchronous call?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Please show us your code and the broker configuration. You can also check the number of message pending in the queue using the activemq console or though jmx.

Comment: I would like to know the reason why this is not possible.Will it update any property in the same connection when i first receive the message from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the message is held by the first consumer that has not ack'd and not been closed.  If you want another consumer to fetch the message than you need to close the consumer or use a transaction and do a rollback to indicate you don't want the message (you would need to configure the redelivery count policy if you don't want retries to the original consumer though).